# Загрузить список в словарь

Tags: python

Есть следующий список из прокси-серверов:

```
['1.2.3.4:80', '12.13.14.15:3128', '123.123.123.123:8080']
```

Как сделать так, чтобы все IP-адреса оказались в списке вот такого вида:

```
proxies = {'http': '1.2.3.4:80', 'http': '12.13.14.15:3128', 'http': '123.123.123.123:8080'}
```

Знаю, что нужно циклом загружать при помощи `for`, но как именно - не могу сообразить.

Comment: Вам ***действительно*** нужен словарь с дублируемыми ключами?

Comment: @kff этого требует документация [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies), при помощи которого я отправляю GET-запросы.

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли документацию. Прокси может быть только один для одного протокола, т.е. один для http, один для https и т.д.

Comment: также `proxies` у вас это *словарь* (а не список), который равен: `{'http': '123.123.123.123:8080'}` (последнее значение среди дублирующихся ключей в константе (dict view) выигрывает).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача приведения списка к словарю с одинаковым ключом не имеет решения, так как

**ключ должен быть уникален**, если все же попробуем это сделать, то получим только последнее значение.

Пример.

```
>>> {'http': '1.2.3.4:80', 'http': '12.13.14.15:3128', 'http': '123.123.123.123:8080'}
{'http': '123.123.123.123:8080'}
```

словарь с дублируемыми ключами не существует по определению. На разных уровнях могут находиться одинаковые ключи, но не на одном. На одном будут переопределяться последующими.